# Numeric value in file name causing OnAction error

Tags: excel

I'm using the following code to assign a new macro to a button:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("ButtonI").OnAction = AName & "!Import_to_Master"
```

where the `AName` is a filename in the format: `"Tool - IP1.xls"`

Currently it throws up:

> Run-time error '1004': Cannot run the macro 'Tool - IP1.xls!Import_to_Master'.

There is no error if there is no numeric value in the filename i.e. if the filename is `"Tool - IP.xls"`.

How can this be solved so that you can use numbers in the filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `'` needed when using workbooks/sheets with spaces in it:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("ButtonI").OnAction = "'" & AName & "'!Import_to_Master"
```

assuming `AName` is "Tool - IP.xls" and is open.

Comment: This did fix the problem, however I don't understand why the same problem didn't occur with other AName that didn't have numbers in them.